# Notificatoin Intent to the app that is running

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I recently added a notification to my test, It has a Countdown Timer in it and when I pick the time and tap the button, the notification is set to the timer and working. but when i hit the home button when the notification is still running, and tap the notification it gets me to a new page of my app not the one that is running. The fix I'm looking to make is to stop the timer when the notification is tapped and get the user to a reset page of my app.

```
//Notification Intent
    final Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this , MainActivity.class);
    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    final NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);



    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {



            if (view.equals(silentButton)) {

                int getvaluehour = numPickerHour.getValue();
                int getvalueminute = numPickerMin.getValue();

                getvaluehour = getvaluehour * 3600000;
                getvalueminute = getvalueminute * 60000;
                long hoursandMinstomils = getvalueminute + getvaluehour;



                final CountDownTimer counter = new CountDownTimer(hoursandMinstomils, 1000) {


                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
                        long millis = millisUntilFinished;
                        //Convert milliseconds into hour,minute and seconds
                        String hms = String.format("Silent ends in: " + "%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
                        myText.setText(hms);




                        //Notification
                        notifyTimer.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                        notifyTimer.setTicker("This is a notification");
                        notifyTimer.setAutoCancel(true);
                        notifyTimer.setContentTitle(hms);

                        //Notification Intent
                        notifyTimer.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

                        //issues the notification
                        nm.notify(uniqueID, notifyTimer.build());

                    }




                    public void onFinish() {

                        myText.setText("TIME'S UP!!"); //On finish change timer text

                        nm.cancel(uniqueID);



                    }
                }.start();





                stopButton.setOnClickListener(
                        new Button.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                counter.cancel();
                                myText.setText("Timer has been reset");

                                nm.cancel(uniqueID);

                            }
                        }
                );



            }
```

Comment: you need to add the android:launchMode="singleTop" to your activity

Comment: Can you be more specific please

Comment: For MainActivity in Android manifest file you need to add this this code android:launchMode="singleTop"

Comment: @SunilKumar The notification is in the onTick of the Countdown Timer so it updates and lauches every second i think thats why its not working

Answer (score 0):

you can set flags to intent for configuring its behavior,for your purpose you can use this

```
 notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Comment: It still gets me to a new activity now the one that is running